# How can i convince Idris that my function is covering?

Tags: idris

I wrote a function `doSomething` that takes an open or closed parenthesis and returns a corresponding `Int`:

```
doSomething : (c : Char) -> {auto isPar : c == '(' || c == ')' = True} -> Int
doSomething '(' {isPar = Refl} = 1
doSomething ')' {isPar = Refl} = -1
```

With `isPar` i want to make sure that only parentheses and no other characters can get passed to `doSomething`. But Idris complains:

```
Error: doSomething is not covering
Missing cases:
    doSomething _
```

How can i convince or proof to Idris that all possible cases are covered?
I tried:

```
doSomething 'a' {isPar = Refl} impossible --this type checks
doSomething _   {isPar = Refl} impossible --this not
```

Comment: curiously also doesn't work with `data Paren : Char -> Type where    Left : Paren '('      Right : Paren ')'` and `doSomething : (c : Char) -> {auto isPar : Paren c} -> Int`

Comment: a hacky soln is obviously to `doSomething _ = 0`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't guess that `(` and `)` are the only values that allow the construction of an `isPar` values, and thus is not able to conclude that the remaining case is impossible.

A workaround is to keep track that something is not an open or a clos parenthesis. It can be done like so:

```hs
import Data.So

doSomething : (c : Char) -> {auto isPar : So (c == '(' || c == ')')} -> Int
doSomething x {isPar} = case (choose (x == '(')) of
  Left _ => 1
  Right notOpen => case (choose (x == ')')) of
    Left _ => -1
    Right notClose => case (soOr isPar) of
        Left isOpen => absurd $ soNotToNotSo notOpen isOpen
        Right isClose => absurd $ soNotToNotSo notClose isClose
```

`So` is a proof that a predicate is `True`, `choose` provides either a proof that a predicate is `True` (the left branch), or a proof that it isn't true (the right branch).
Using the proof that `x` is neither `(` (`notOpen`) nor `)` (`notClose`), we can conclude by analysing why `isPar` is true (with `soOr`).

You can find the type of all the functions I used to deal with `So` in [its package](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/base_docs/docs/Data.So.html).

Comment: it seems to me like the compiler could in theory infer the function is exhaustive, if it just started its search for all cases at the proof rather than the char

Comment: It might with a non-primitive type (I didn't checked), but it can't on a primitive type I think as it can't list the elements of `Char`.

Comment: And more importantly, the compiler don't have any clue that `(` and `)` are the only values that allow you to find a `isPar` value.

Comment: ah yes, I was thinking if you used the `Paren` type in my comment below the question. Then it can list all the instances of `Paren` and infer the corresponding `Char`s from that. But even that doesn't compile

Comment: indeed the error message for that case if matching on `doSomething {isPar=Left} _ = 1` (and the same for `Right`) really gives away just how much the compiler's missing a trick "Missing cases: doSomething _", i.e. it seems to be bothered by the matching on `isPar` rather than the `Char`

Comment: Yes, as `isPar` depends on `c`, the compiler isn't able to pattern match on `isPar` for every `c`.
It's a weird corner case, I'll check if it's a corner case that is the consequence of the use of dependent types or if it's a bug/limitation of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `with` expression to obtain an implementation that I think is a bit more elegant than using `So`, which I try to reserve only as a last resort.

```
||| Test if a Char is an open or close paren.
isParen : Char -> Bool
isParen '(' = True
isParen ')' = True
isParen _ = False

||| Obtain the integer code corresponding to a paren.
||| Proof is required that c is '(' or ')'.
parenCode :
  (c : Char) ->
  {auto 0 prf_isParen : isParen c === True}
  Integer
parenCode c with (isParen c)
  parenCode '(' | True = 1
  parenCode ')' | True = -1
  parenCode _   | False impossible
```

If we perform the comparison inside the `with`, the compiler is able to recognize `isParen c` as identical to the expression as in our `prf_isParen`.

This generates Scheme code that you would hope for:

```lisp
(define Misc-isParen
  (lambda (arg-0)
    (cond ((equal? arg-0 #\() 1)
          ((equal? arg-0 #\)) 1)
          (else 0))))

(define Misc-with--parenCode-8826
  (lambda (arg-0 arg-1 arg-2)
    (cond
      ((equal? arg-0 #\() (cond (else 1)))
      (else (cond (else -1))))))

(define Misc-parenCode
  (lambda (arg-0)
    (Misc-with--parenCode-8826 arg-0
                               (Misc-isParen arg-0)
                               'erased)))
```

Although the `with` generates an extra function call, it only invokes one character comparison.

Also, the Chez compiler is smart enough to optimize away these nested functions:

```lisp
(expand/optimize
  '(let ((Misc-isParen
           (lambda (arg-0)
             (cond ((equal? arg-0 #\() 1)
                   ((equal? arg-0 #\)) 1)
                   (else 0))))
         (Misc-with--parenCode-8826
           (lambda (arg-0 arg-1 arg-2)
             (cond ((equal? arg-0 #\() (cond (else 1)))
                   (else (cond (else -1))))))
         (Misc-parenCode
           (lambda (arg-0)
             (Misc-with--parenCode-8826 arg-0
                                        (Misc-isParen arg-0)
                                        'erased))))
  (Misc-parenCode #\()))
```

```lisp
(Misc-with--parenCode-8826 #\( (Misc-isParen #\() 'erased)
```

---

You can also use `with` in this manner to *construct* the required proof that `isParen c === True`, by using the extra `proof` binding:

```
parenCodeTry : (c : Char) -> Maybe Integer
parenCodeTry c with (isParen c) proof prf_isParen
  _ | False = Nothing
  _ | True = Just $ parenCode c
```

In the `True` branch of `parenCodeTry`, the type of `prf_isParen` will be:

```
prf_isParen : Equal (isParen c) True
```

which will allow the compiler to find a value for the `auto 0 prf_isParen` parameter.

In the `False` branch of `parenCodeTry`, it will be:

```
prf_isParen : isParen c = False
```

which of course is *not* a valid value for the `auto 0 prf_isParen` parameter, and therefore you would not be able to invoke `parenCode` in that branch.